# Dynamic PHP image from iFrame?

Tags: php, image, iframe, dynamic

I would like to know if there is a way to essentially take a snapshot of a webpage. Take this example: http://ffaat.pointclark.net/blog/archives/42-Dynamically-Generated-Text-Images.html where he is able to dynamically generate an image based on a text parameter (like so: http://ffaat.pointclark.net/blog/templates/rob2/img/titleimage.php?text=Hello%20Stack%20Overflow%20People!%20Help%20me%20out%20here.&px=18 ). However, can I go a step further and grab a would-be iFrame widget and convert this to a dynamic PHP image? I would use the widget's JavaScript code, but it's not working; however, that is not the topic of this discussion.

If this is possible, great, but I'll make due if not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to linux than you can learn about ffmpeg , ffmpeg is very powerful in creating dynamic screen shots and convert them to videos as well , As ffmpeg is not very common you will find less tutorial and you will have to spend lot of time, 1 thing is for sure with ffmpeg you will never mess up with quality, it is that good , even youtube use ffmpeg to convert mp4 movies to flv

http://linuxers.org/tutorial/ffmpeg-tutorial-beginners